# Factoring with fractional exponents

Tags: factoring

I don't know what it is, but this problem is giving me problems, although i have solved similar ones, this one is in all likely hood very simple, it's just :
Solve for X
$\sqrt{x} + (1 + \sqrt{x}) -2 = 0$

Comment: You can think about the equation $y + 1 + y -2 = 0$

Comment: Let $t = x^{1/2}$. Quadratic equation.

Comment: Set $\sqrt  x=t$ and multiply by $t$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the equation you pose is $$\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - 2 = 0$$

To solve that, multimply by $\sqrt{x}$ and then square.
$$
(x+1)^2 = 4x$$

The only solution is $x=1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: multiply through by $\sqrt x$.

Hint 2: try a substitution, for example $x^2=y$.